# Markdown: force two consecutive words to be on the same line

Tags: markdown

As the title says, using `markdown` I need to force two consecutive words to stay on the same line, as follows:

> silly question

and not

> silly 
>  question

Is it possible with `markodwn` to avoid a line break at a specified location ?

Answer (score 4):

You should add a non-breaking space in your markdown. Either use your system's special-characters-picker, or use HTML in your markdown:

```
silly&nbsp;question
```

In pandoc for example, this works even when exporting to LaTeX.